# Spark missing batch details

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

We're trying to resolve some performance issues with spark streaming using the application UI, but the batch details page doesn't seem to be working. I'm expecting to see something like this: [image]

But instead we get this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApF8z.png[image]

Any ideas why we aren't getting any job details? Is there an option we need to enable to see these details?

We are running Spark 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from Spark 1.5.0 to Spark 1.6.1 solved the issue.